# Android/java: Transition / Migration from ProGuard to R8?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard, android-r8

I wonder how to make the transition / migration from **ProGuard** to **R8**.

Should I just remove the Proguard-related lines from my Gradle files and add the `android.enableR8 = true` line instead ?

Thanks.

Comment: Folks, you may find this helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60786850/4694013

Answer (score 46):

Proguard is developed and maintained by GuardSquare while R8 is developed and maintained by Android team which means they are two different products although R8 is compatible with Proguard.

As seen from here https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/proguard-and-r8

> **Compatibility of ProGuard and R8**
>
> The good news for developers is
> that R8 is backward compatible with ProGuard. If you have a working
> ProGuard configuration (maybe eclectically copied from Stackoverflow),
> you can carry that over to R8. It currently still ignores some
> options. Notably, R8 doesn't implement the options -whyareyoukeeping
> and -addconfigurationdebugging, which we consider essential to quickly
> get to a working configuration, as we've explained in a previous blog.

Yes, `android.enableR8 = true` will enable the R8 feature.

Also note that, R8 does not currently (as the time of Android Studio 3.2.1) support Android Archive Library (AAR) projects. It is used only when building APK files.

---

**Edit #1**

From [@Archie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9291997/archie-g-qui%C3%B1ones),
If you are using Gradle plugin version **3.4.0** and above, **R8** is **on** by default.

See: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#r8-default

---

**Edit #2**

For the transition from Proguard to R8, you can follow below steps:

**1. Disable Proguard**

Update the `buildTypes { }` configuration to disable Proguard, e.g. for `release` build type:

```
   android {
       ...
       buildTypes {
           release {
               useProguard false // <-- disable proguard
               minifyEnabled true // <-- enable minification
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
       ...
   }
```

On Android Studio 3.4, `useProguard` by default is `false`. And R8 is enabled by default.

**2. (*Optional*) Set full R8 configurations report file**

Add below line into your `proguard-rules.pro` to output a full report of all the rules that R8 applies when building your project.

```
// You can specify any path and filename.
-printconfiguration <your-path>/full-r8-config.txt
```

**3. Generate the obfuscated app.**

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

**4. (*Optional*) Fine-tune and trouble shooting**

Find your `<your-path>/full-r8-config.txt` to fine-tune the configuration or do trouble shooting if any.

**References:**

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#configuration-files

Comment: Would you know where to enable `android.enableR8 = true` ? I encountered this for a "old" empty project (Just did a string of Android Developer updates). I couldn't work out where to enable the setting so I wiped the project and created a new one in the hopes I could add that information as a comment, but after grepping the new files I find I have no entry for this line.

Comment: Add this line to gradle.properties

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've just started making head way into Android applications.

Comment: if you are using Gradle Version 3.3.0 and above, R8 is on by default. See: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#r8-default

Comment: R8 is turned on by default starting with 3.4.0, not 3.3.0. The part of the changelog that you've linked is for 3.4.0.

If you're interested in some of the behavioral differences between ProGuard and R8, the company I work for, PreEmptive Solutions, has put together some documentation that tries to cover that here: https://r8-docs.preemptive.com/.

Comment: One more thing is that `useProguard` will be deprecated from the DSL.
If anyone wants to keep using proguard instead of R8, set `android.enableR8 = false` in gradle.properties.
See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129758703

Comment: @shizhen: any way to fix this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57736108/proguard-problem-after-updating-to-android-gradle-plugin-3-5 as I know useProguard is going to get deprecated. But this issue happens with enabling r8