# When using R8 on Android, do I need to uninstall my existing Proguard?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard, android-r8

Do I need to remove Proguard related code from Gradle when using R8?

```
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921486/8034839 may be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't actually remove the proguard rules, as R8 works with Proguard rules in **compat mode**. For more details, please refer to https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/r8-new-code-shrinker-from-google-is.html.

> R8 is available with Android Studio 3.3 beta and works with Proguard rules. To try it, set the following in your project's `gradle.properties` file:
>
> ```
> android.enableR8=true
> ```

But for the **full mode**, it is not directly compatible with Proguard.

---

**Edit #1**

Check here for how to migrate Proguard to R8: [Android/java: Transition / Migration from ProGuard to R8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921486/8034839)