# proguard-rules.pro does not seem to work with R8

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-r8

I upgraded my Android Studio to 3.4 earlier today, and I am using the default shrinker R8 for the first time. I copied the contents of `proguard-project.txt` of a library project to its `proguard-rules.pro`. `proguard-project.txt` worked flawlessly for this project that generates an aar file for use by other app projects.

File `proguard-rules.pro` does not seem to be used.   The project has the   following in its `build.gradle`:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Release
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Debug
        }
    }
```

`proguard-rules.pro` has the following:

```
# Preserve all public classes, and their public and protected fields and methods.
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
```

The public methods' names are not preserved at all:
[image]

Could anyone offer a tip on how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this line to `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableR8 = true
```

And try below code inside your `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep public class ** {
    public *;
    protected *;

}
```

---

**Edit #1**

Check here for how to migrate Proguard to R8: [Android/java: Transition / Migration from ProGuard to R8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921486/8034839)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
    public *;
    protected *;
did it.  The others seem to be unnecessary.

Comment: Do we need the first line to enable R8? I thought it was enabled by default in the new version of android studio.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo No.  I do not have the first line, and it is working fine now.  I believe you are right - it is enabled by default starting from Android Studio 3.4.

Comment: This was a bug, see http://issuetracker.google.com/131712625. The issue is fixed and will be part of Android Studio 3.4.1.

Comment: As of June, 2023, this was the solution that worked for me. I upgraded my gradle version and all of a sudden the R8 builds were obfuscating some files that should not have been and my production builds were breaking with zero changes to the proguard rules on my end. Adding the public and protected lines as mentioned above fixed it, but I was minutes away from downgrading gradle to go back to proguard instead of R8 again.