# Class no longer obfuscated after upgrading to Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

After upgrading to Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0, a basic class no longer gets obfuscated.

The following basic steps can reproduce the problem:

1. In Android Studio create a new empty project
2. In `app/build.gradle` change `minifyEnabled` to `true`
3. Create the following class, `ProguardTestClass.java`:

   ```
   public class ProguardTestClass {

       public interface ProguardTestInnerInterface {
           void proguardTestCallback(String message);
       }

       public static void proguardTestMethod(String input, ProguardTestInnerInterface impl) {
           impl.proguardTestCallback("proguardTestMethod received input=[" + input + "]");
       }
   }
   ```
4. Refer to the class from `MainActivity.java`:

   ```
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
           private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

               ProguardTestClass.proguardTestMethod("MainActivity's ProguardTestClass", new ProguardTestClass.ProguardTestInnerInterface() {
                   @Override
                   public void proguardTestCallback(String message) {
                       Log.d(TAG, "Proguard test: " + message);
                   }
               });
           }
       }
   ```
5. Confirm that it's using Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0 in `build.gradle`
6. Confirm that it's using `gradle-5.1.1` in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
7. Open a Terminal window in the Terminal tab
8. Run `./gradlew clean build`
9. Run `find . -name mapping.txt | xargs grep "ProguardTestClass -> "`

**Expected output:**

```
com.example.proguardgradleplugin340.ProguardTestClass -> com.example.proguardgradleplugin340.a:
```

**Actual output:**

`app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt` does not mention any renaming of `ProguardTestClass`.

To see that prior Android Gradle plugin versions could produce the expected output, repeat the steps above but point to prior versions of Android Gradle plugin and Gradle:

5. Change to Android Gradle plugin 3.3.2 in `build.gradle`
6. Change to `gradle-4.10.1` in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

I tried to investigate by looking into other [diagnostic files that we used to get from Proguard](https://medium.com/@maheshwar.ligade/de-obfuscate-stack-traces-6e19a52a3379), but they're no longer output (at least not by default anyway):

`find . -name seeds.txt`
`find . -name usage.txt`

I also checked the Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0 release notes and found out that it replaced Proguard in favor of a new technology that ["integrates desugaring, shrinking, obfuscating, optimizing, and dexing all in one step"](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#behavior_changes).

Comment: Yeah they replaced Proguard with new R8

Comment: Folks, you may find this helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60786850/4694013

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set `useProguard false` to let the plugin use R8 instead of ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your app’s code and resources. E.g.

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false 
        }
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, if you want to stick to ProGuard, you should disable R8 from `gradle.properties` like below:

```
# Disables R8 for Android Library modules only.
android.enableR8.libraries = false
# Disables R8 for all modules.
android.enableR8 = false
```

And remember to set **`useProguard true`**.

---

**Edit #1**

Check here for how to migrate Proguard to R8: [Android/java: Transition / Migration from ProGuard to R8?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921486/8034839)

Comment: Disabling R8 from `gradle.properties` and setting `useProguard true` fixed the problem.  Now `find . -name mapping.txt | xargs grep "ProguardTestClass -> "` shows the expected mapping occurred: `com.example.proguardgradleplugin340.ProguardTestClass -> com.example.proguardgradleplugin340.a:`.  However the first suggestino (set `useProguard false`) did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @shizhen is what I accepted as the solution to the problem.  But I wanted to document an alternative in case anyone else runs into this problem.

I was able to make R8 obfuscate the class by actually instantiating the class.  Notice how my original code for `ProguardTestClass` contained no constructor and I used it in a fairly static way.  But when I added a constructor and instantiated it from `MainActivity.java`, that gave R8 a reason to obfuscate it I guess.

Revised `ProguardTestClass` that made R8 perform the obfuscation:

```
public class ProguardTestClass {

    //
    // NEW CODE: BEGIN
    //
    private int avar;

    public ProguardTestClass(int avar) {
        this.avar = avar;
    }

    public int incrementValue() {
        return ++avar;
    }
    //
    // NEW CODE: END
    //

    public interface ProguardTestInnerInterface {
        void proguardTestCallback(String message);
    }

    public static void proguardTestMethod(String input, ProguardTestInnerInterface impl) {
        impl.proguardTestCallback("proguardTestMethod received input=[" + input + "]");
    }
}
```

Then in `MainActivity.java` I instantiated and called the `ProguardTestClass` on `onCreate()`:

```
    proguardTestClass = new ProguardTestClass(3);
    Log.d(TAG, "Proguard test: " + proguardTestClass.incrementValue());
```