# R8 issue: Unable to set up Proguard minifyEnabled because of error GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: android, android-r8

Error while generating release bundle with `minifyEnabled true` option. Here are the Gradle settings which give me the error:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

I also see that task transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8For... takes too much time (up to 10-20 mins)

The error:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` in Gradle task transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForCommonRelease

Comment: may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818404/android-java-transition-migration-from-proguard-to-r8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of turning of R8 a solution will be to raise the JVM heap size for the gradle daemon by adding/changing the value of `org.gradle.jvmargs` in `gradle.properties` (in the root of the Adroid Studio project):

```
  org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2G
```

If that is not enough try going to 4G. The memory use of R8 have been growing, and for 3.4 there has been OOM issues on some apps.